# jQuery UI tabs - how to delay loading all tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I have a set of tabs that are all loaded via ajax (e.g. via the href in the tab links, [per the docs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)).

But the tabs are in a containing element that may be hidden when the page first loads (such as a collapsed accordion pane, or within a parent tab group on a tab that's not initially selected, in a hider, etc.).

I'd like the initially selected tab not to fire off immediately on page load, but to trigger it in code when the parent element becomes visible.  I do have the ability to fire code when that happens, but I don't have control over when the tabs are instantiated - they will be created via `$('#myTabs').tabs({...})` on page load, so I can't just instantiate the tabs in the "show" code (I wish!).

Is there a way to either simply not have *any* tab selected, or to tell the selected ajax-loaded tab to just skip it until I programmatically kick it off?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `collapsible` and `active` options:

```
$("#myTabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    ...
});
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active):

> Setting `active` to `false` will collapse all panels. This requires the `collapsible` option to be `true`.